# What Replaced setSplitLate() in iText7?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext7

I have:

```java
// Create PDF Table for blahz t = new Table(colsWidth); 
t.setWidth(750);   
t.setWidthPercent(100);   
t.setKeepTogether(true);  
t.setKeepWithNext(true);
```

However, table rows are still 'bleeding' over onto the next PDF page.

I suspect that `setKeepTogether()` and `setKeepWithNext()` are optimized for cells, not tables.

That said, has anyone 'dug up' the iText7 replacement for: `setSplitLate()`?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

although both methods you mention are members of the [Cell](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.13/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Cell.html) class, the [Table](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.13/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Table.html) class has also the exact same methods (inherited from [BlockElement](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.13/com/itextpdf/layout/element/BlockElement.html) class)